# codeigniter - form returning no data

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

I'm trying to create a page with a form using ci. 
When i submit the form, the controller says that I have no data that's been submitted. 
I can't see where my error lies.

Here's the view:

```
<?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
<?php echo form_open('widgets/search/'.$hardwaremodel.'/'.$objectid.'/'.$name.'/'.$fd); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="search">Last 4 characters of address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="searchstring" placeholder="last 4 characters" size="4">
</div>          
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
 <button type="cancel" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
</form>
```

Once the page renders, the form tag ends up looking like this:

```
<form action="http://myserver/myciapp/index.php/widgets/search/205406zl/5461/SW-1/SW1net" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
```

The controller:

```
public function search()
{
    $searchstring = $this->input->post(); // form data
    var_dump($searchstring);
    exit;    
}
```

The results of the `var_dump` shows:

```
bool(false)
```

Thanks

**EDIT 1**

I haven't posted the entire HTML page that includes the form... but I display some of the fields passed in the URI as headings on the page - just before I create the form.  Hope that clarifies...
Would this impact the POST data?  Why is that relevant?
Thanks

Comment: I cannot see the controller name in url. Have you used CI routing for that?

Comment: the controller name is "widget" which is auto created by the call to form_open.  I hope i understood your question...

Comment: Why this `/205406zl/5461/SW-1/SW1net` in your URL. You're not doing anything with them within your controller

Comment: Are you adding those variables in the form_open tag for a reason? I don't see anything in there about what it is used for.

Comment: @CraineRunton please see my Edit 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form elements are referenced by name attribute which is missiong on input field `searchstring`.

Add:

```
name="searchstring"
```

on your input field.

Comment: In CI 2.1.4, you don't have to call a `name` if you want to collect all POST items.

Comment: @Craine: This is something not about CI whatever version it is. Something is missing on HTML.

Comment: @hsuk Sorry, you are correct. What I meant was that by calling `$this->input->post()` without a `name` attribute will return all POST items. I forgot that without a `name` attribute, the form item will never be POSTed. My apologies.

Answer (score 1):

A few things I'd suggest doing. First is, if you are going to include other variables in the `form_open` tag, I would add those variables to your controller, and put them in the `form_open` tag as URI strings. This will allow the form validation to work if you are going to echo out validation errors.

Also, you should be calling a name on the `input->post()` to get the specific item, (but you don't need to to get all POST data).

**Controller:**

```
public function search($hardwaremodel, $objectid, $name, $fd) {
    $searchstring = $this->input->post('search_string'); // form data
    var_dump($searchstring);
    exit;    
}
```

**View:**

```
<?php echo form_open('widgets/search/'.$this->uri->segment(3).'/'.$this->uri->segment(4).'/'.$this->uri->segment(5).'/'.$this->uri->segment(6)); ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="search">Last 4 characters of address:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="search string" name="search_string" placeholder="last 4 characters" size="4">
</div>
```

Comment: Craine, I originally had a specific variable name I was looking for in the post data, but.. for debugging purposes, I changed the var-dump statement just to print everything to see what was going on.  but +1 for your comments

Comment: No problem. I know I've forgotten to put names back in before myself.

Answer (score 0):

in this code you have not used `name` attribute.You use id.
try this one

```
<input type="text" name="searchstring" value="xyz">
```